# TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-api

I am using Google Places services Api and it was working in version 3.53 and it stopped working after that, so I debugged and found that the error is

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Code:

```js
const containerRef = React.useRef();
React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
        const autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
            new google.maps.Map(containerRef.current)
        );
    } catch (err) {
    }
}, []);
```

The line `new google.maps.Map(containerRef.current)` is giving this error.

I have tried to assign the values to different variables like

```js
const containerRef = React.useRef();
React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
        const autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(containerRef.current);
        const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
            map
        );
    } catch (err) {
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: that would suggest `containerRef.current` isn't a `Node` - what is it? use console.log to find out

Comment: @JaromandaX
It contains Autosuggest as it is used in that tag only which contains (props , state , suggestioContainer , autowhatever
context
: 
{}
highlightFirstSuggestion
: 
ƒ ()
input
: 
undefined
itemProps
: 
ƒ (_ref4)
justMouseEntered
: 
false
justPressedUpDown
: 
false
onBlur
: 

ƒ (_ref5)
state
: 
{isFocused: false, isCollapsed: true, highlightedSectionIndex: null, highlightedSuggestionIndex: null, highlightedSuggestion: null, …}
storeAutowhateverRef
suggestionsContainer
updater
_reactInternalInstance
_reactInternals

Comment: how is `Autosuggest` a DOM Node?

Comment: @JaromandaX
containerRef.current contains a Object Autosuggest {props .....................} like this and typeof containerRef.current is an object but the same thing was working in v3.53 and it stopped working from 3.54 version

Comment: Is it a DOM Node?

Comment: if (containerRef.current instanceof Node) {
  console.log("It's a DOM node!");
}
else{
console.log("It's not a DOM node!");
}
I am using this code to check whether it is DOM or not , it is coming in else condition 
So it is not a DOM @JaromandaX

Comment: there's the issue then

Comment: But if I change version to 3.53 then it is working so what can be problem , I checked in previous version that it was not a DOM but still working